# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I'm trying to insert the form data in cloud Firestore database. Below is my x.component.ts file in which I'm getting error at constructor where I'm writing

```js
private firestore: AngularFireStore

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { GroupService } from '../shared/group.service';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    // import { NullTemplateVisitor } from '@angular/compiler';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    // import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
    // import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-group',
      templateUrl: './group.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./group.component.css']
    })
    export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private groupService: GroupService, private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.resetForm();
      }
    
      resetForm(form ?: NgForm){
        if(form!= null)
          form.resetForm();
        this.groupService.formData = {
          $key : null,
          firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
          age: null
        }
      }
    
      onSubmit(form : NgForm){
        let data = form.value;
        // this.firestore.collection('groups').add(data);
        this.resetForm(form);
      }
    
    }
```

The error I get is as below.

`ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options! at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8895) at resolveToken (core.js:9140) at tryResolveToken (core.js:9084) at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8981) at resolveToken (core.js:9140) at tryResolveToken (core.js:9084) at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8981) at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21217) at _createClass (core.js:21270) at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21234)`

I had followed the links below but no luck.

[Angular Fire Issue 1706](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1706)

[Angular Fire Issue 1416](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1417)

[No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837133/no-provider-for-injectiontoken-angularfire2-app-options)

Below is my app.module.ts file.

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment'
    import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { AngularFirestoreModule, AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { GroupsComponent } from './groups/groups.component';
    import { GroupComponent } from './groups/group/group.component';
    import { GroupListComponent } from './groups/group-list/group-list.component'
    import { GroupService } from './groups/shared/group.service';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
    
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        GroupsComponent,
        GroupComponent,
        GroupListComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [AngularFirestore, GroupService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please share the NgModule where you are importing the firebase modules including firestore.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Uploaded the file

Comment: If I had to make an educated guess, you need to definitely remove AngularFirestore from providers in your module. It is not supposed to be added there. It is available throughout your app once you import the AngularFirestoreModule. Remove it from providers and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Same error if I removed it from providers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know the answer which solved my problem. I just had to import the below statement to the service I created and need to create object in constructor of service.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Answer (score 12):

I don't know in which version of AngularFire this changed, but if you add AngularFire Auth via `ng add @angular/fire`, you'll also encounter this error as soon as you try to import `AngularFireAuth` in a component.

This can be fixed by importing `FIREBASE_OPTIONS` from `@angular/fire/compat` and adding the following to the `providers` section in your `module.ts`:

```
{ provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase }
```

Thanks to [Saumya](https://software-testing.com/topic/366351/no-provider-for-injectiontoken-angularfire2-app-options-ionic6/2#1) for this fix.

Answer (score 3):

The error is most likely coming from attempting to add `AngularFirestore` to `providers` of your `AppModule`. `AngularFirestore` becomes available to inject when `AngularFirestoreModule` is imported into the module. Remove `AngularFirestore` from `providers`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'
import { GroupsComponent } from './groups/groups.component';
import { GroupComponent } from './groups/group/group.component';
import { GroupListComponent } from './groups/group-list/group-list.component'
import { GroupService } from './groups/shared/group.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GroupsComponent,
    GroupComponent,
    GroupListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [GroupService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please also note the updated import paths. These paths come directly from the [installation documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md).

Also make sure you only have `@angular/fire` in your dependencies and not both `@angular/fire` **and** `angularfire2`. With that being said, only reference `@angular/fire` in your imports and remove `angularfire2` from your `package.json` and any imports.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The import for AngularFireDatabaseModule is incorrect. Can you please try changing the import for that module to `import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';`. Without that change, I get an error that prevents the application from even starting. Please see the updated question and the updated firebase module imports.

Comment: @Virus Can you also please confirm the `@angular/fire` version you have in your `package.json`? Also can you confirm that you do not have both `@angular/fire` and `angularfire2` in your `package.json`, that you only have `@angular/fire`.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to import AngularFirestore from

`import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`

Instead of
`import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';`

hope it helps someone