# NullInjectorError trying to use AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use AngularFire (I'm using Ionic Capacitor, only iOS and Android, no web application).

I followed a tutorial and added angularfire to my application. When I run I get an error:
`Error: Uncaught (in promise) NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(LoginPageModule) .... NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!`

This is my LoginPageModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FirebaseService } from 'src/app/services/firebase.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    FirebaseService
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

This is FirebaseService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export interface User {
  uid: string
  displayName: string
  email: string
  photoURL: string
}

export interface Goal {
  id: string,
  dueDate: number,
  title: string,
  category: string,
  isAchieved: boolean,
  createdAt: number,
  createdBy: string,
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})



export class FirebaseService {
  currentUser: User = null;


  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log("Changed: ", user);
      this.currentUser = user;
    })
  }
}
```

I saw that there is multiply threads about this, but it seems like adding the imports of AngularFirestore and AngularFireAuth fixed it, but not in my case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837133/no-provider-for-injectiontoken-angularfire2-app-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding  `AngularFireModule` but I believe you have added it incorrectly

Try below

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
...

import: [
  ...
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
]
```

In your env file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '<your-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-project-authdomain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-URL>',
    projectId: '<your-project-id>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>',
    messagingSenderId: '<your-messaging-sender-id>',
    appId: '<your-app-id>',
    measurementId: '<your-measurement-id>'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseService has the property `providedIn: 'root'` but you're adding it on providers array of LoginPageModule, hence you're creating two instances of this service. You must remove FirebaseService from the `LoginPageModule` providers array.