# Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/kartik/Desktop/Ecommerce/ecommerce/node_modules/firebase/index")'. ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am a beginner at FireBase and I am trying to implement Google login with FireBase using angular. I am getting the above error at auth. I am hereby attaching login.component.ts and dev depencencies of package.json, package.lock.json.

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/auth';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private afAuth:AngularFireAuth) {
    firebase.default.database
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  Login(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()) //error due to this line.
  }

}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.4-canary.9a26fbe",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "firebase": "^8.6.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.10.2",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
```

**package-lock.json**

```
...

"@angular/fire": {
      "version": "6.0.4-canary.9a26fbe",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/fire/-/fire-6.0.4-canary.9a26fbe.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-LVskM344FFLQ34Dyc6ngN6n+c8kZODm3T3Sdzu43P4wmpaoocL06/3HMvXlQiwBdE3bH+F+tdGu2VYxgQZCWCA==",
      "requires": {
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
      }
    },

...

"angularfire2": {
      "version": "5.4.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/angularfire2/-/angularfire2-5.4.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7brktOHPObHgMnCN+QkakyCBr2mnxMxMSVLlEZ7OF70LjFIQz/RV3t5a7cH1SjystbY+kzR3qYvn/irlWs27/Q==",
      "requires": {
        "@angular/fire": "5.4.2"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/fire": {
          "version": "5.4.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/fire/-/fire-5.4.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-QzB5d1wtqr9jxfsVNv2+569MlfK4/QrrpNy0IngOHdxS4FBbXqMOcx37iv1m2mzJv9zlGUddUX44IZP5Xfb3cw=="
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Why are you using an older version of angular-fire? In the latest versions the syntax changed a little but would you be willing to update your dependency versions?

Comment: May be due to tutorial video, by the way /i am using angularfire 6.0.4 canary. Please suggest me the new syntax and I'll reinstall it @latest.
Another part is I accept I am beginner at firebase please don't downvote my questions arem't we here to help each other?

Comment: The new syntax is `import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';`, `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`, `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`. I found this video helpful, check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP5zw7fjQgo&ab_channel=Fireship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are the old ones. I suggest you to update them and use the new syntax:

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

with `firebase@7.24.0`

There complete tutorial about firebase authentication which I find really useful; here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP5zw7fjQgo&ab_channel=Fireship)

The old imports are

```js
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

Comment: working ,but on runtime it's throwing error: ```NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!```

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837222/5706293

Comment: This is causing error ```TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { auth, database, messaging, storage, firestore, functions } from 'firebase/app'; error``` and no stackoverflow solution is working

Comment: What are you trying to import?

Comment: Nothing, the error is from app.module.d.ts

Comment: app.module.d.ts or app.module.ts? Could you add the app.module to your question?

Comment: Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:26 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'messaging'. Did you mean to use 'import messaging from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { auth, database, messaging, storage, firestore, functions } from 'firebase/app';

Comment: Could you add the imports and the firebase version you're using now to your question?

Comment: ```    
"angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase": "^8.6.2",
```
This is written in package.json
though firebase -V command is giving 9.11.0

Comment: But if you have a package-lock.json, that doesn't matter that much. Did you update the package-lock as well?

Comment: yes, i uninstalled all dependencies and reinstalled it

Comment: If you simply deleted the node_modules and ran `npm i` again that won't work. It will still download what you have in your package-lock

Comment: i meant i uninstalled angularfire2, firebase and firebase-tools using npm uninstall.. then reinstalled it

Comment: Ok rather than version 8, could you try `npm install firebase@7.24.0` ?

Comment: then     this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
this line is giving error

Comment: what's the error? and could you please double check your imports --e.g: `import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';`? I have no idea about where you're importing the firebase modules.

Comment: make sure the steps in the video are working fine for you , it's throwing hell lot of errors in my machine independent of firebase versions.

Comment: I did make sure ofc :-) I have multiple apps running on firebase

Comment: Are you sure the versions are correct in your package-lock? or maybe you can check them in your node_modules?

Comment: It's working I had to add ``` import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth'; ```
 and ``` import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';```
 in app.module.ts.
Please mention this in your answer along with firebase version 7.24.0. It will help readers rather than reading so long comments.

Comment: That doesn't make sense tho. You are importing both from `angularfire2` and `@angular/fire`. How is that possible?

Comment: I mean I imported AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireDatabaseModule in app.module.ts; kept firebase version 7.24.0 and imported the imports in the way you suggested and it worked, even I don't know how it worked but I tried different PnC suggested online. like import ... from angular/fire over import ... from angularfire or prefer import feom firebase/app rather than import ... from firebase.
I am happy it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hehe I'm glad you figured it out!